# C# : Open a folder of a remote PC into the Windows files explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, connection, remote-access

I want to open a folder of a remote PC into the Windows files explorer
: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKezS.png)

I wrote the following method :

```
private void openComponentFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            #region Connexion to the bench
            ImpersonatedUser iuImpersonatedUser = new ImpersonatedUser(BenchInfos.Current.UserName, "user", BenchInfos.Current.PcPassword);

            iuImpersonatedUser.LogOn();
            #endregion

            Component component = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Component;

            if (component != null)
                if (Directory.Exists(component.Path))
                    Process.Start(component.Path);

            #region Disconnexion
            iuImpersonatedUser.LogOut();
            iuImpersonatedUser.Dispose();
            #endregion
        }
```

When I click on a Component on a wpf treeview, I connect to the remote PC (with the UserName  `BenchInfos.Current.UserName`, the domain `"user"`, and the password `BenchInfos.Current.PcPassword` of the PC), and if the Component path (`component.Path`) exists on the remote PC, the folder (`component.Path`) should be open in the Windows files explorer. Finally I disconnect to the remote PC.

However, when the method is run, the access to the folder is denied ("Accès refusé") while the path exists:
[image]

Moreover, in other method, I'm able to read files in `component.Path` folders...

So why, am I not able to open the folder into the Windows file explorer and what can I do to make it working ?

Thank you for your help.

Rémi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
private void openComponentFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Component component = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Component;

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = "net",
        Arguments = "use " + Path.Combine(ConfigMorphee.Instance.PcPath, "c$") + " /user:" + BenchInfos.Current.UserName + " " + BenchInfos.Current.PcPassword
    };

    Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo };

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (component != null)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(component.Path))
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(component.Path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Catch MainWindow - openComponentFolder_Click ", ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```